# How to implement Observable Design Pattern in Web Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, observer-pattern

I wonder If I could implement [Observable](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) design pattern in ASP.Net MVC 3.

I want that every time an information like a value existing on the server, the browser should be notified when there is a change.

Can I do this? If yes, how? Please post examples or link to such examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few things you should take a look at before you start building your own.

First, SignalR

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx

Second, read this article that was just recently posted about the Trello web stack. They talk about how they implemented client side updating.

http://blog.fogcreek.com/the-trello-tech-stack/

(The pushing and pulling section)

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_polling#Long_polling

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker

Or as simple method use javascript for pinging server time to time to ask if new data exists, and load it when it occured.

Comment: Yeah, I know this one,but I was wondering if there is any way that the request comes from the server without being asked for by the client.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

The only true thing that allows server to push data to client is web workers, all other stuff is keeping HTTP connection open long time and send data via it. In this case server really pushes data to client (but client may need to keep connection alive by performing some activity on it) but this solution is not very robust.